# Addressing a Boot-Failure without a keyboard or an OS

Tags: boot, bios

I recently received a new computer with an Intel Core i5 Processing Unit, running with a DP55KG Mother Board (which I bought a long time ago). I wanted to install Ubuntu. However, whenever I switch the computer on, I look at the post codes being displayed on the mother board. It seems to be going fine, until it gets stuck on "E6", never reaching "00". This leads me to the point where I am unable to boot the computer and connect any hardware device to it.

I think, I need to update the BIOS but I have no idea.

Comment: http://downloadmirror.intel.com/18129/eng/DP55KG_TechProdSpec.pdf contains the post codes. See page 73.